# Read and write images in pixels in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read and write a grayscale image using `BufferedImage`. But the pixels in the writing images  are a little bit different from its source. I am not good with this image processing stuff. Please anyone help me to find the mistake that i have made in my code.

Here is my code

```
File InImage=new File("source.jpg");
File OutImage=new File("out.jpg");

/* code for reading the image*/
BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(InImage);
WritableRaster raster=image.getRaster();

/*  writing the same raster to a new image */
BufferedImage newImg=new BufferedImage(raster.getWidth(), raster.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
                newImg.setData(raster);
ImageIO.write(newImg, "jpg", OutImage);
```

Comment: Can you show the source and output image ? Remmber Jpg is a lossy format, so in decompressing and re-compressing the same image can result in a different image especialy if the compression settings are different

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ToGray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("f:/lion.jpg");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        int[][] pixel = new int[width][height];
        Raster raster = img.getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                pixel[i][j] = raster.getSample(i, j, 0);
            }
        }

        BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int value = pixel[i][j] << 16 | pixel[i][j] << 8
                        | pixel[i][j];
                theImage.setRGB(i, j, value);
            }
        }

        File outputfile = new File("f:/op.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(theImage, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e1) {

        }
}
}
```

This code is just a sample to read and write images which are gray scale.Here I have used raster to read image and set rgb to write image.
You can also use get and setRGB to read and write image.
The format of image written must be either bmp,gif,png etc.Since jpg,jpeg are lossy compression after  writing in those formats we may get full black image.On seeing the array value of image we may get 0 or 1 or 2 values as pixel intensity.Hence,use png.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. But why saved images all are black-white?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure the original image is not of type `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`. I suggest you output the same image type as the input one:

```
BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(raster.getWidth(), raster.getHeight(), image.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

[JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a [lossy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format, reading it in and writing it out is going to lose information from the image so it is going to look different each time you save it.

To avoid this, use a non-lossy format such as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I mess with images try it out, its designed for bitmaps but you can edit it to do jpg and png. it loads them to an array of bytes for handling. this is the most basic working version i can find as I've developed it further since

```
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ImageEdit 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //loadBitmapToBytes("icon","resources");
        //WriteByteToBitmapFile("foo", "food", null);
    }



    public static byte [] loadBitmapToBytes (String filename, String dir) throws IOException
    {
        String a = "\\\\";
        String b = ".bmp";
        String readDir = dir + a + filename + b;
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(readDir));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", baos);
        byte[] img=baos.toByteArray();
        return img;
    }

    public static void writeByteToBitmapFile (String filename, String dir, byte [] img) throws IOException
    {   
        String a = "/";
        String b = ".bmp";
        String writeDir = dir + a + filename + b;
        BufferedImage imageA = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(img));
        ImageIO.write(imageA, "BMP", new File(writeDir));
        System.out.println(writeDir);
    }

    public static byte [] invertBitmap(byte[] img)
    {
        int indexNo = 54;

        for(int i = 54; i < (img.length-54)/3; i++)
        {
            img[indexNo] = (byte) (255-img[indexNo]);
            indexNo++;
            img[indexNo] = (byte) (255-img[indexNo]);
            indexNo++;
            img[indexNo] = (byte) (255-img[indexNo]);
            indexNo++;
        }
        return img;
    }

    public static byte [] invertSingleBitmapChannel(char chanel, byte [] img)
    {
        String a = "Color Chanel bad Input";
        int indexNo = 54;
        for (int i = 54; i < (img.length-54)/3; i++, indexNo++ )
        {
            if (chanel == 'B' || chanel == 'b')
            {

                img[indexNo] = (byte) (255-img[indexNo]);
                indexNo+=2;

            }
            else if (chanel == 'G' || chanel == 'g')
            {
                indexNo++;
                img[indexNo] = (byte) (255-img[indexNo]);   
                indexNo++;
            }
            else if (chanel == 'R' || chanel == 'r')
            {
                indexNo+=2;
                img[indexNo] = (byte) (255-img[indexNo]);   
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(a);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return img;

    }

    public static byte [] greyFromBitmapColor(char fromColor, byte [] img)
    {   
        int temp;
        int indexNo = 54;
        String a = "Color Chanel bad Input";
        for(int i = 54; i < (img.length-54)/3; i++, indexNo++)
        {   
            if (fromColor == 'B' || fromColor == 'b')
            {
                temp = img[indexNo+2];
                img[indexNo] = (byte) temp;
                indexNo++;
                img[indexNo] = (byte) temp;
                indexNo++;
            }
            else if (fromColor == 'G' || fromColor == 'g')
            {
                temp = img[indexNo+1];
                img[indexNo] = (byte) temp;
                indexNo+=2;
                img[indexNo] = (byte) temp; 
            }
            else if (fromColor == 'R' || fromColor == 'r')
            {
                temp = img[indexNo];
                indexNo++;
                img[indexNo] = (byte) temp;
                indexNo++;
                img[indexNo] = (byte) temp; 
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(a);
                return null;
            }
        }

        return img;
    }

    public static byte [] greyFromBitmapAverage(byte [] img)
    {
        int temp;
        int indexNo = 54;
        for(int i = 54; i < (img.length-54)/3; i++, indexNo++)
        {
            temp = (img[indexNo]+img[indexNo+1]+img[indexNo+2])/3;
            img[indexNo] = (byte) temp;
            indexNo++;
            img[indexNo] = (byte) temp;
            indexNo++;
            img[indexNo] = (byte) temp;
        }

        return img;
    }

    public static byte [] removeChannelFromBitmap(char lostColor, byte [] img)
    {
        String a = "Color Chanel bad Input";
        int indexNo = 54;
        for(int i = 54; i < (img.length-54)/3; i++, indexNo++)
        {
            if (lostColor == 'B' || lostColor == 'b')
            {

                img[indexNo] = 0;
                indexNo+=2;

            }
            else if (lostColor == 'G' || lostColor == 'g')
            {
                indexNo++;
                img[indexNo] = 0;   
                indexNo++;
            }
            else if (lostColor == 'R' || lostColor == 'r')
            {
                indexNo+=2;
                img[indexNo] = 0;   
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(a);
                return null;
            }
        }

        return img;
    }

    public static byte [] greyFromDominantBitmapColor (byte [] img)
    {
        int indexNo = 54;
        long r = 0;
        long g = 0;
        long b = 0;
        char dom = 'b';

        for(int i = 54; i < (img.length-54)/3; i++, indexNo++)
        {   
                b += img[indexNo];
                indexNo++;
                g += img[indexNo];
                indexNo++;
                r += img[indexNo];  
        }

        if (b > 0)
            dom = 'b';
        if (g > b)
            dom = 'g';
        if (r > g)
            dom = 'r';

        greyFromBitmapColor(dom, img);
        return img;
    }

}
```

and here's the test class

```
  import java.io.IOException;

public class TestApp {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        byte [] img = ImageEdit.loadBitmapToBytes("fooInv","resources");
        //ImageEdit.invertBitmap(img);
        //ImageEdit.greyFromBitmapColor('r',img);
        ImageEdit.greyFromDominantBitmapColor(img);
        //ImageEdit.invertBitmap(img);
        //ImageEdit.writeByteToBitmapFile("fooInv", "resources", img);

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```